# D1 mini esp8266 error: esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header

Tags: esp8266, pins, bootloader, flash

I am pretty sure this device worked yesterday. I tried to short GPIO0 to ground (flash), nothing.
I have a second ESP that uploads fine, but this one does not.

Is their another way to get this bootloader to open up? Or am I the owner of a brand new door stop?

Comment: show the complete wiring. is it a board or a basic module?

Comment: "doorstop", heh; maybe for a dollhouse ;) Does serial monitor show anything, like garbage, when you reset it attached?

Comment: @Juraj It's USB. I should have been more specific. There is no way to screw it up.

Comment: @dandavis Yes, I see a single line of garbage going across the screen in the serial monitor.

Comment: sorry I missed D1 mini in the tile. is something wired to the board?

Comment: @Juraj Nope. My friend. Just the USB

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this will help EVERYONE, but I hope it at least helps someone.  I had the same issue with several different boards (3 Nano's, 2 NodeMCU ESP8266's, and 1 Uno).  I searched and searched for an answer and I kept reading about this pin or that pin being "pulled low" or "pulled hi" interfering with uploading sketches.  Well, since I couldn't find a solid answer anywhere I decided to disconnect all of the peripherals hooked to my board (except for powers and grounds) and Wah Laa!!!  The sketch uploaded like it was supposed to.  So, I believe if you just unhook all of the sending and receiving pins from all of your peripherals during upload, the sketch should upload just fine.  I hope this helps you.

Comment: I would just like to thank you for the surprising solution. I was on the verge of going bonkers searching for a solution.

Comment: You're welcome!  I'm glad it helped.  It is definitely tied to one of the I/O pins.  It depends on what board you're using, but these boards usually have at least one pin that will not let any code upload if "pulled" up or down (depending on what it's expecting).  I believe you can look these pins up through the board data sheets/specs.

Answer (score -1):

You must use the Arduino only as a pass-thru! -> So  for programming the the esp8266, you need  to BRIDGE  the Arduino-RESET to GROUND!

Comment: why? it is enough to not have Serial activated in the ATmega